# Prevent multiple ifelse statements in php

Tags: php, strings

I'm trying to figure out a way to make my code more readable and maintainable. While rewriting some ugly spaghetti code, I stumbled across this:

```
if($header !== null && $fieldValue === null)
{
    $errorMessage =  $message . ': row ' . $row . ', header "' . $header . "\"\n";
}
elseif($header === null && $fieldValue !== null)
{
    $errorMessage =  $message . ': row ' . $row . ', field value "' . $fieldValue . "\"\n";
}
elseif($header === null && $fieldValue === null && $row === null)
{
    $errorMessage =  $message . "\n";
}
elseif($header !== null && $fieldValue !== null)
{
    $errorMessage =  $message . ': row ' . $row . ', header "' . $header . '", value "' . $fieldValue . "\"\n";
}
```

It must be possible to make this more efficient, but how? Do I use a switch statement? Please enlighten me.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! What task does this code accomplish? Please tell us, and also make that the title of the question via [edit]. Maybe you missed the placeholder on the title element: "_State the task that your code accomplishes. Make your title distinctive._". Also from  [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._".

Comment: Thank you Sam. I've got my answer, but I will think of this the next time I post something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<?php

function buildErrorMessage($message, $row = null, $header = null, $fieldValue = null) {

    if ($row) {
        $message .=  ": row {$row}";
    }

    if ($header) {
        $message .=  ", header {$header}";
    }

    if ($fieldValue) {
        $message .=  ", value \"{$fieldValue}\"";
    }

    return $message;
}

// Tests
echo buildErrorMessage('one');
echo buildErrorMessage('two', 2);
echo buildErrorMessage('three', 3, 'header');
echo buildErrorMessage('four', 4, 'header', 'value');
echo buildErrorMessage('five', null, null, 'value');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm going to check this later today/this evening. I'll let you know if this is what I'm looking for!

Comment: I've checked this out and I'm not sure why I didn't think of this in the first place. Also I didn't even realize that string interpolation was possible in PHP. I've learned something today, thanks again!

Comment: @user3478148 note for string interpolation you need to use double quotes around strings and the {} are not necessary unless you butt a variable name up against test eg "{$test}ing" vs "$testing" the first one will replace the var $test, the 2nd one won't

Comment: [Please refrain from answering questions that are likely to get closed.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6389/35991)

Comment: In am not a mind reader. The question seems fine to me and was flagged after I had answered it.